# Regular expression to match (name="myName".*house="myHouse"|house="myHouse".*name="myName") without using OR

Tags: python, regex

I am writing a regular expression which needs below criteria to satisfy.

```
(name="myName".*house="myHouse"|house="myHouse".*name="myName")
```

Either name or house can come first. My Regex should match both.

Actually my real code is even more bigger after writing the repeated code.

Is there any way to use the regular expression without Repetition like above ?

Comment: The snippet you gave us looks like something from a DOM element, or some other structured text.  If so, then you should be using a _parser_ to check attributes, not regex.  Consider going in this direction if you don't want to live with long and ugly alternations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use positive lookahead assertions for this. It's a bit jejune, but if you're trying to keep things simple, it should work. What you want to do is confirm:

```
I am looking at .*house

    AND

I am looking at .*name
```

without regard to the lengths of the two `.*` parts.

So, since lookahead expressions are *zero width* (that is, they match without actually consuming any characters - they just "look ahead") you can paste together as many as you'd like.

Please be aware: doing this can get really expensive, performance-wise. You will have to scan, and then re-scan, for each extra term that you match. If the strings you are matching against are long, this will slow you down a lot.

Sample regex:

```
(?=.*name="myName")(?=.*house="myHouse")
```

Comment: Why the restriction on not using `|` ?

Comment: Also, try tying it to start-of-text, if possible. `(?= ^ .* name)` (note: caret)

Answer (score 1):

The only possible way to do this without the | pipe operator is to do two separate regex searches. So the answer is no, there is no other way.

Also, if this is XML or HTML that you are searching, it is highly advised that you use a parser such as Beautiful Soup instead of regex.